# Prove $\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n)$ = a $\cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$.

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

---

**Question:**

If $a_n$ upholds $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb {N}$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = a$ and $b_n$ is a bounded sequence:

Prove $\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n)$ = a $\cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$.

---

So there is one point in the proof where I am stuck.

**This is what I have so far:**

$b_n$ is bounded $\implies$ exists some $b_{n_k}$ s.t $\lim_{k \to \infty}b_{n_k} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}bn =$ sup $b_n$.

Notice, $a_{n_k}b_{n_k}$ is a subsequence of $a_nb_n$, then from this knowledge and arithmetics of limits we have:

$\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n) \geq \limsup_{k \to \infty}(a_{n_k}b_{n_k}) = a \cdot $ sup$b_n = a \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$.

$\implies \limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n) \geq a \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$ and this is the first inequality.

**The second one is where I am struggling.**

Since $b_n$ is bounded and $a_n$ converges to $a$ we have $\exists \limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n)$.

$\implies \exists a_{n_p}b_{n_p}$ subsequence of $a_nb_n$ s.t $\lim_{p \to \infty}(a_{n_p}b_{n_p}) = \limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n)$.

Also, $\exists i \in \mathbb {N}$ s.t $\forall x \gt i$ we have $a_n \lt a+\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \gt 0$. We know $b_n \lt$ sup$b_n$.

$\implies a_{n_p}b_{n_p} \lt (a+\epsilon) \cdot$ sup$b_n$.

**Here lies the part I'm insecure about:**

Taking limit on both sides we will get:

$\limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n) = \lim_{p \to \infty}(a_{n_p}b_{n_p}) \leq a \cdot$ sup$b_n = a \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$.

$\implies \limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n) \leq a \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$ which is the second inequality.

$\implies \limsup_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n) = a \cdot \limsup_{n \to \infty}b_n$ as needed.

Comment: By "blocked" do you mean bounded?

Comment: @BrunoB yes pardon my English.

Comment: It's fine, don't worry, plus it was still understandable.

Comment: "$b_n$ is bounded $\implies$ exists some $b_{n_k}$ s.t $\lim_{k \to\infty}b_{n_k} = \limsup_{n \to \infty}bn =$ sup $b_n$"

$$$$
$"=\sup b_n"$ is false here, for example if $b_n = 1/n,$ then $\sup b_n = 1 \neq 0=\limsup b_n.$

Comment: It is convenient to use $$a_nb_n=(a_n-a)b_n+ ab_n$$ The first part tends to $0,$ hence its impact on $\limsup$ is neutral.